# Windows Folder Share API

Tags: c++, winapi, file-sharing

is there a WIN32 API available to manage folder sharing in Windows? Some links to examples will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, since Windows 2000 Professional there's a networking API available in netapi32.dll which provides this functionality. Functions like NetShareAdd, NetShareCheck, NetShareDel let you manage the shared files. See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525393(VS.85).aspx

for more information,

Answer (score 0):

There is [a tutorial for doing this with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Share-Folder-c_.aspx), might be some help?